# Trouble with change properties

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, singleton, uwp

I have some properties in my singletone class and I want change them from another two classes.

Singletone class:

```
public class EditModeSwitcher:ViewModelBase//MVVMLight Libs
{
    private bool isOriginalImgVisible;

    private static EditModeSwitcher instance;

    public EditModeSwitcher()
    {
        this.isOriginalImgVisible = false;
    }

    public static EditModeSwitcher Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new EditModeSwitcher();

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public bool IsOriginalImgVisible
    {
        get { return this.isOriginalImgVisible; }
        set
        {
            this.isOriginalImgVisible = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged("IsOriginalImgVisible");
        }
    }
}
```

I left just one property because there are similar. Next I made an instance in `App.xaml`

```
<viewModels:EditModeSwitcher x:Key="EditModeSwitcher"/>
```

And where I need on my `MainPage.xaml` I added

```
Visibility="{Binding IsOriginalImgVisible,Source={StaticResource EditModeSwitcher}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

When it launch `Visibility` properties work, but I cant change it.
What Im do:

Use button to Execute the command

`MainViewModel:BaseViewModel`

```
 private async void PickExecute()
    {
        EditModeSwitcher.Instance.IsFilterImgVisible = true;
        EditModeSwitcher.Instance.IsOriginalImgVisible = true;
        EditModeSwitcher.Instance.IsUserControlVisibile = false;
    }
```

But my View doest catch this and all elements are hide(defaults value in EditModeSwitcher`s constructor), but on debugging properties changed their values

And another view model

`ImageManipulatorViewModel:BaseViewModel`

```
 public async void MakeCollageExecute()
    {
        EditModeSwitcher.Instance.IsFilterImgVisible = false;
        EditModeSwitcher.Instance.IsOriginalImgVisible = false;
        EditModeSwitcher.Instance.IsUserControlVisibile = true;
    }
```

What Im doing wrong? Why my View page doest change `Visibility` property?

Comment: Have you set the *DataContext* properly?

Comment: @Romasz Yes i did. Its   `<Page.DataContext>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="MainViewModel"/>
    </Page.DataContext>`  But its `MainVM` because I need source Binding from there

Comment: Can you try to bind like this: `Visibility="{Binding Instance.IsOriginalImgVisible,Source={StaticResource EditModeSwitcher}...`? I think you are referring to two different objects - one class is created with `<viewModels:EditModeSwitcher x:Key="EditModeSwitcher"/>` in resources and second is an instance inside. Though they have both some static properties, INotify needs to reffer to the same class.

Comment: @Romasz yes its helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating two classes of your *EditModeSwitcher* - one within resources with line `<viewModels:EditModeSwitcher x:Key="EditModeSwitcher"/>` and the second in `instance = new EditModeSwitcher();`.

Though they have some static fields/properties, but the *RisePropertyChanged* needs to be run on the same one class - it's not static. It should work, if you change your binding to:

```xml
Visibility="{Binding Instance.IsOriginalImgVisible,Source={StaticResource EditModeSwitcher}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```